# Emacs frame background color and default face background are set equal, but appear different by #010101

Tags: emacs

I've set the frame background color and the default face background color to
both be #262626:

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(background-color . "#262626"))
(set-face-attribute 'default nil
                    :background "#262626")
```

In spite of this, they render slightly differently:

[image: Broken rendering.]

The difference is just barely noticeable. If you look at this in GIMP or
similar, you can see that the background where there is text is #262626, while
the background where there is no text (the blank lines) is #252525. This bothers
me.

Strangely, the same thing does not occur when setting #242424 for both:

[image: Non-broken rendering.]

So why not just use #242424 and be done with it? I insist on #262626 because I
want Emacs to be the same color as my xterms, and my xterms are that color
because it's number 235 in the 256-color table. I want 256-color-capable apps
running in xterm to be able to exactly reproduce the background color.

My question, then: How do I get Emacs to render the frame background and text
background the same?

(I realize I sound like a crazy person for caring about this, but there's no
reason why it shouldn't work properly and it's driving me nuts.)

This is Emacs 24.3 on Arch Linux.

Comment: Doesn't your second setting take care of everything, such that the first setting is not needed?  If you have `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :background "#262626")`, why do you need anything else?  Maybe Arch Linux is different, but on OSX it is not necessary to use `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(background-color . "#262626"))`

Comment: In addition to looking for a workaround by asking here for help, consider filing an Emacs bug report / enhancement request: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  Even if there is a good rationale or explanation for the current behavior you see, perhaps there is room for improvement.

Comment: @lawlist I just tested it, and it seems you're right about the frame parameters being added automatically. I wanted to make doubly sure that everything was being set properly, but in this case it's redundant. Unfortunately, the same problem still happens even without the redundant setting.

Comment: Yes, you should file a bug, I have noticed this on OSX as well.

Comment: It appears that someone else has had the same problem: http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=16395 . I suppose I will have to poke around in the mentioned C source files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha! I have discovered the problem. It's an accursed rounding error.

- This is bzr rev 116690 (git commit 08885465fcc080f369f0958fcd85e37e28a7526f).
- `./autogen.sh`, then:

  ```
  ./configure --prefix=/opt/emacs/usr --sysconfdir=/opt/emacs/etc \
      --libexecdir=/opt/emacs/usr/lib --localstatedir=/opt/emacs/var \
      --with-x-toolkit=gtk3 --with-xft CFLAGS=-g
  ```
- Install dirs are under `/opt/emacs` to avoid clobbering the existing install.
- `make`, `(sudo) make install`, `gdb src/emacs`.

The culprit function is `xg_set_widget_bg` in `src/gtkutil.c`. Set a breakpoint
at line 1039, which sets the background from floating-point color values:

```
gtk_widget_override_background_color (w, GTK_STATE_FLAG_NORMAL, &bg);
```

In my case, the first call to `xg_set_widget_bg` is irrelevant. The second is
where the fun happens. Poke the struct:

```
Breakpoint 1, xg_set_widget_bg (f=0x1209908, w=0x1658110, pixel=2500134) at gtkutil.c:1039
1039          gtk_widget_override_background_color (w, GTK_STATE_FLAG_NORMAL, &bg);
(gdb) print xbg
$1 = {pixel = 2500134, red = 9764, green = 9764, blue = 9764, flags = 7 '\a', pad = 0 '\000'}
(gdb) print bg
$2 = {red = 0.14898908979934386, green = 0.14898908979934386, blue = 0.14898908979934386, alpha = 1}
(gdb) print bg.red * 0xffff
$3 = 9763.9999999999982
(gdb) print bg.red * 0xff
$4 = 37.992217898832678
(gdb) set bg.red = bg.green = bg.blue = (double)0x26 / 0xff
(gdb) print bg
$5 = {red = 0.14901960784313725, green = 0.14901960784313725, blue = 0.14901960784313725, alpha = 1}
(gdb) print bg.red * 0xffff
$6 = 9765.9999999999982
(gdb) print bg.red * 0xff
$7 = 37.999999999999993
```

`cont`, and see the problem magically disappear. Debuggers are pretty cool.

If you want to see how Emacs gets the values in `xbg`, also look at `xfns.c`.
When you say `(set-background-color "#262626")`, Emacs turns each component into
0x2600 and then asks X for the closest color value. Here, that's 9764 (0x2624).
You can verify this with `xmag`, since it reports 16-bit components.

Apparently, GTK is scaling its pixel values to 0xff, and there's enough error to
make it round (floor?) to 37 (0x25) instead of 38 (0x26). Text rendering is done
somewhere else and doesn't have the same problem.

In the end, I suppose it's mostly GTK's fault. I don't really want to touch the
GTK source for now, but at least I know what's going on.